# HTTPS between frontend and backend

Tags: vue.js, ssl, web, https

I am developing a website using Vue.js, and I have implemented HTTPS in my webpage.

Right now the website is basically static, no communications between itself and the backend server.

If I wanted to add features for instance, login, via a backend server which is on the same machine as the frontend server.

Do I need to get another SSL certificate to make to communication between frontend and backend through HTTPS?

Is there any way to make the SSL certificate work on the whole domain?

Comment: Check out https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here

1. [Proxy API requests](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) to your backend service

   This means that your HTTP server (eg NGINX) uses your built Vue app (eg the `dist` folder contents) as its document root and creates a reverse proxy for requests to your API service. For example, say you have a backend service running on port 3000

   ```
   location /api {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/
   }
   ```

   Then your Vue app can make requests to `/api/whatever`.

   During development, you can mirror this using the [`devServer.proxy`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) setting in `vue.config.js`

   ```js
   module.exports = {
     devServer: {
       proxy: {
         "^/api": "http://localhost:3000/"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use a [wildcard certificate](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/wildcard-domain-step-by-step/58250) and run your backend service at a sub-domain, eg

   - Frontend - https://example.com
   - Backend - https://api.example.com
3. Just get two SSL certificates for your two domains. They're [free](https://letsencrypt.org/) after all

---

Keep in mind, options #2 and #3 will need you to enable CORS support whereas that is not required for option #1.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I will definitely try out these options.

Comment: I would definitely preference option #1 since it's the easiest for both development and production if both services are running on the same machine